# How to use the spring boot tests correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I do not really understand how to properly use the tests in Spring. Do I really need to perform a full initialization of the entire Spring configuration to run the test?

I have a final integration test, a normal controller call, and checking its response. I have to do it this way:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    HomeRestController homeRestController;
    @Test
    @Repeat(value = 15)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        RequestSearch requestSearch = new RequestSearch();
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        requestSearch.setMonth(7);
        requestSearch.setYear(2018);
        requestSearch.setGbNumber(5010);
        requestSearch.setPayTime(new Double(32));
        requestSearch.setScanTime(new Double(2.7));
        requestSearch.setWaitTime(new Double(35));
        ReportResponse reportResponse = homeRestController.find(requestSearch, httpServletResponse);

        Assert.assertTrue(reportResponse.cashBoxPlans.size() == 1487);
        Assert.assertTrue(reportResponse.getExcelPath().equals("ExceReport.xls"));

    }
}
```

Having looked at the Spring documentation I found one of the perfect examples and wanted to add a separate class with the test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HomeRestController.class)
public class RestControllerMockTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        RequestSearch requestSearch = new RequestSearch();
        requestSearch.setMonth(7);
        requestSearch.setYear(2018);
        requestSearch.setGbNumber(5010);
        requestSearch.setPayTime(new Double(32));
        requestSearch.setScanTime(new Double(2.7));
        requestSearch.setWaitTime(new Double(35));
        mvc.perform(post(HomeRestController.postUrl,requestSearch).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());    
    }
 }
```

But this test does not work, this is the exception that is being thrown:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [ru/denisa/configuration/SQLServerDatabaseConfiguration.class]:
```

The configruation class mentioned in the exception (`SQLServerDatabaseConfiguration`) is a configuration class annotated with `@Configuration`.

If I add the following annotation to my test:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Then I get the following exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [ru.denisa.test.service.rest.RestControllerMockTest]:
```

How to do it right? Thanks!

Comment: In your pom.xml, did you include `com.h2database` dependency for test scope?

Comment: The `@WebMvcTest` should only construct a context containing a minimal web configuration and dependencies for the controller should be mocked using `@MockBean`. The main issue is that you are configuring things which Spring Boot should be configuring. Why are you manually configuring an `EntityManagerFactory` (and probably more things) that Spring Boot can configure (and automatically exclude).

Comment: short answer is **yes**. long answer is **yes, how else do you think all the injection magic will happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApp.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RestControllerMockTest {
@Autowired
HomeRestController homeRestController;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

}
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! Magically AutoConfigureMockMvc=)

Answer (score 1):

a little bit simpler code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HomeRestController.class)
public class RestControllerMockTest {

}
```

PS. for disable security just change  `@WebMvcTest(controllers = HomeRestController.class, secure= false)`

Comment: Thaks for your addition!